# How can I retrieve Instagram post data using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I have a question regarding a code I wrote using selenium to retrieve information about an Instagram post such as the number of likes and comments, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Can anyone help me out?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
posts_data = []
driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/p/{target_link}")

# get number of likes
try: 
    likes_count = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5 > span')[0].text
        
except:
    likes_count = "N/A"

# get number of comments
try:
    comments_count = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5 > span')[-1].text
    
except:
    comments_count = "N/A"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Based on the above code, it seems that the user was attempting to use Selenium to retrieve information about an Instagram post, specifically the number of likes and comments. However, it appears that the code is not working as expected and is returning "N/A" values for both the like count and comment count.

To troubleshoot this issue and provide a solution, I would need more information on the specific error message or behavior that the user encountered while running this code.